# Programs running on Nvidia show black screen

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

### What is the problem?

Since saturday my laptop is suddenly giving out weird black screens when some programs run on my Nvidia card. (GTX 950m) I didn't know what was going on so I just decided to run the program on my built in graphics card (Intel HD 520) and suddenly they worked again. I have tried multiple things trying to fix it but I have yet to succeed. When the window is resized you can see that the program is running correctly and it flickers for just a small second.

### Example

[image: GIF]

### List of programs that have this

- Discord
- Atom
- Minecraft Launcher

I haven't tried any other programs yet.

### What have I tried?

- Wiping the Nvidia drivers using [DDU](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) and reinstalled them
- Searching online for solutions; haven't found anything yet.

I really hope this could get fixed because it is really annoying

Comment: did you try reinstalling the latest nvidia drivers for your device?

Comment: Yes. As stated in the thread I wiped them and reinstalled them.

Comment: Also tried to use DDU for this @FrankThomas

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for a while. Fixed it by upgrading the Intel GPU driver from 21.xxx to 24.xxx

Answer (score -2):

I think it's hardware problem, not software. Looks like your Nvidia card is dying or dead.

Comment: Welcome to superuser; your answer could very well be correct but it would be a better answer if you could add a bit more detail, how could this be tested (have to go to a computer shop,etc), Is there a manual that could checked, a website of use and so on. This would help them check and accept your answer. again welcome to superuser, thankyou for taking the time and maybe [answer] will help with the superuser way and why.